# Recursive Descent vs Lex/Parse?

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis

I think I understand (roughly) how recursive descent parsers (e.g. Scala's Parser Combinators) work: You parse the input string with one parser, and that parser calls other, smaller parsers for each "part" of the whole input, and so on, until you reach the low level parsers which directly generate the AST from fragments of the input string

I also think I understand how Lexing/Parsing works: you first run a lexer to break the whole input into a flat list of tokens, and you then run a parser to take the token list and generate an AST.

However, I do not understand is how the Lex/Parse strategy deals with cases where exactly how you tokenize something depends on the tokens that were tokenized earlier. For example, if I take a chunk of XML:

```
"<tag attr='moo' omg='wtf'>attr='moo' omg='wtf'</tag>"
```

A recursive descent parser may take this and break it down (each subsequent indent represents the decomposition of the parent string)

```
"<tag attr='moo' omg='wtf'>attr='moo' omg='wtf'</tag>" 
  -> "<tag attr='moo' omg='wtf'>"
       -> "<tag"
       -> "attr='moo'"
            -> "attr"
            -> "="
            -> "moo"
       -> "omg='wtf'"
            -> "omg"
            -> "="
            -> "wtf" 
       -> ">"
  -> "attr='moo' omg='wtf'"
  -> "</tag>"
```

And the small parsers which individually parse `<tag`, `attr="moo"`, etc. would then construct a representation of an XML tag and add attributes to it.

However, how does a single-step Lex/Parse work? How does the Lexer know that the string after `<tag` and before `>` must be tokenized into separate attributes, while the string between `>` and `</tag>` does not need to be? Wouldn't it need the Parser to tell it that the first string is within a tag body, and the second case is outside a tag body?

EDIT: Changed the example to make it clearer

Comment: A lexer would produce something like `LEFTANGLE IDENT=tag IDENT=attr EQ STRING=moo IDENT=omg`, etc.

Comment: @SK-logic: Edited the question to clarify. My confusion is if there was a `attr='moo'` _outside_ of the tag body, how would the lexer know not to break it up into `IDENT=tag`, and just tokenize it as one big text node?

Comment: Ok, I see - it would not tokenise that stuff as a single large string with a lexer, you'll have to deconstruct a string back (loosing all the whitespaces, of course).

Comment: You have the wrong concept of how this works.  State is handled by recursion.  Your code would start by seeing the Left Angle bracket, then branch off into a ReadTag method.  The ReadTag method would call ReadParameter when it sees an identifier.  Thus your context is held within the ReadTag method.  If there was never a left angle bracket then the parts outside of the tag would enter a different subroutine and probably be treated like text in there.  This is where Recursive Descent gets its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the lexer will have a "mode" or "state" setting, which changes according to the input.  For example, on seeing a `<` character, the mode would change to "tag" mode, and the lexer would tokenize appropriately until it sees a `>`.  Then it would enter "contents" mode, and the lexer would return all of `attr='moo' omg='wtf'` as a single string.  Programming language lexers, for example, handle string literals this way:

```
string s1 = "y = x+5";
```

The `y = x+5` would never be handled as a mathematical expression and then turned back into a string.  It's recognized as a string literal, because the `"` changes the lexer mode.

For languages like XML and HTML, it's probably easier to build a custom parser than to use one of the parser generators like yacc, bison, or ANTLR.  They have a different structure than programming languages, which are a better fit for the automatic tools.

If your parser needs to turn a list of tokens back into the string it came from, that's a sign that something is wrong in the design.  You need to parse it a different way.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that these languages that require "context-sensitive tokenizing" would require duplicating some of the parser-logic in the lexer (in terms of having the lexer's state machine partially match up with the Parser's state machine), which sort of defeats the lexer/parser separation of concerns if you make heavy use of lexer-state? And that recursive-descent is more general (even if less nicely-segregated) than one-step lexing/parsing?

Comment: Usually the lexer state would be managed by the lexer itself.  The examples above can be done that way.  I'm sure there are examples where the parser would communicate with the lexer to change its state.  But I agree with your statement.  If you have to do a lot of that, the language is not a good fit for those tools, and recursive descent, or even an ad hoc parser is better.  I think FORTRAN falls into this category.  It predates the automated tools, and also much of formal parsing theory, and the only way to parse it is with a fully custom parser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is something that has been bugging me for a while, especially because most times when i ask about "parsing" I only hear about "regexs" and "lex/yacc" or "tokenizer/parser", and I always thought recursive descent (parser combinators) felt more natural for some pretty simple cases. Good to know I'm not crazy =).

Answer (score 2):

> How does the Lexer know that the string after  must
>   be tokenized into separate attributes, while the string between > and
>    does not need to be?

It doesn't.

> Wouldn't it need the Parser to tell it that the first string is within
>   a tag body, and the second case is outside a tag body?

Yes.

Generally, the lexer turns the input stream into a sequence of *tokens*. A token has no context - that is, a token has the same meaning no matter where it occurs in the input stream. Once the lexing process has completed, each token is treated as a single unit.

For XML, a generated lexer would typically identify integers, identifiers, string literal and so on as well as the control characters, like '<' and '>' but not a whole tag. The work of understanding what is an open tag, close tag, attribute, element, etc., is left to the parser proper.